# Problemas con el ancho de un texto en css y html

Tags: html, css

tengo problemas con una etiqueta "p" en una etiqueta "div" con Id´s "mensaje-encriptado" y "recuadro-mensaje" respectivamente. Necesito crear una anchura para el texto que esta en "p", este texto proviene de un "textarea" que pasa por un código de javascript, cambia unas vocales. El problema viene cuando, establezco una anchura para la etiqueta "div" y trato de que el texto que se supone que está en "p" esté dentro de esta anchura delimitada, pero al parecer no, el texto que está en "p", se sigue a renglon seguido, no hace una salto de línea cuando debe de hacerlo ¿alguien sabe que se debe hacer?

```css
.recuadro-mensaje{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    
}

.recuadro-mensaje{
    position: relative;
    left: 800px;
    top: 90px;

    max-width: 600px;

    font-family: 'Chivo Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #0A3871;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

                
  <img src="rectangulo.jpg" alt="rectangulo" class="recuadro">
  <img src="muñeco.jpg" alt="muñeco" class="muñeco" id="lupa">
  <p class="noencontrado" id="hola">No se ha encontrado ningún mensaje</p>
  <div class="recuadro-mensaje"><p id="mensaje-encriptado">//aquí debe de estar el texto//</p></div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: Yo probé el código y hace salto de línea cuando corresponde. Solo que en el código que has puesto no corresponde hacerlo

Comment: ¿Podrías poner una imagen de cómo quieres que se vea y cómo se ve ahora?